# Renaming a file on log out

Tags: php, authentication, rename, lamp

I'm trying to rename a file with PHP but for some reason it doesnt work, do I have to activate some special permissions under PHP?

heres my code for the php file

```
<?php
  if(!rename('file.php','filer.php'))
  {
    echo "Couldn't rename file!";
  }
  else 
  {
    echo "file renamed succesfully!";
  }
?>
```

I'm trying to rename a file on my `/var/www` directory when they sign out of a login area, so that way they cant access back hitting back button. Do I have an error on my code? Or is there another way to prevent this?

Comment: Is error reporting set to E_ALL?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea...how will the file ever get changed back? How will any other visitors get to the file? Why not just store a boolean `$loggedIn` in the session and just destroy the session when they log out. Check on each page to make sure they're logged in, otherwise redirect to the login page.

Comment: Oh my, yeah I didn't read the bottom part when I answered to be totally honest.  This is, indeed, an awful idea for a whole lot of reasons and you should do as Travesty suggests.

Comment: @travesty Thank you for your idea, ust to be clear, you mean when I validate the user and password make a variable $loggedin and pass it through other pages as $_POST?

Comment: No, not $_POST. Read up on how to use [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default permissions on this folder `/var/www/` are: `chmod 755 /var/www/`

"read, write, and execute by owner" and "read and execute by the group and everyone else"
(-rwxr-xr-x)

and the files inside the folder `/var/www/file` are: `chmod 644 /var/www/file`

I don't know if you have changed the Permissions or simply execute this command and it we'll work.

`chmod 777 /var/www/file.php`

"read, write, and execute by owner, group and everyone else"

Comment: Isn't it a bit unsafe to let everybody have write access to the file?

Comment: Yes it is, but he must look for his right permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, then...it will make a copy of the file under a new name and them delete the original:

```
copy('file.php','filer.php');
unlink('file.php');
```

You aren't trying to move the file the code is being called from, are you?

Comment: Why is this preferable to `rename()`?

Comment: It's not, I just gave OP different code that does the same thing in case by some fluke it works.  I don't have time to deal with config files and whatnot, I just popped on the site to read something and didn't even plan on answering anything.

Comment: I apologize if that's the case, I was just offering a passing thought on my way through since there weren't any answers.  Well, at least people can read these comments now.

Answer (score -1):

PHP must have write access to the file. (I assume that you have a UNIX system). First find out which user PHP runs as, by running this command:

```
echo `whoami`;
```

in the PHP interpreter. (On my system that's `www-data`). Then run:

```
sudo chown www-data file.php
```

in the shell, in the same directory as the file you want. Of course, change `www-data` to the PHP user on your system. Make sure that the owner has write permissions. Then you're done; PHP can rename this file.

Comment: Just to make sure it's obvious, those are backticks surrounding whoami, not quotes.